# Node.js not returning the result

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node testing work, i keep calling the functions, whenever i call the function i am not getting the result in browser, in case if i giving wrong "routes" then i properly getting resut in browser as the error..

why my functions returning result not appearing in browser?

here is my function :

```
function route (handle, pathname) {

    console.log ("About to route a request for " + pathname);

    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){

        handle[pathname](); // but nothing display in browser.

    } else {

        console.log ("No request Handler for " + pathname);

        return "404 Not Found"; //it works fine. ( display the message )

    }

}

exports.route =  route;
```

my Method is called properly too.. here is my methods:

```
function start() {
    return "Hello Start"; // nothing display in browser
}

function upload() {
    return "Hello Upload"; // nothing display in browser
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

what should be the issue? I should suppose to get the result in browser right?

**UPDATE :**

In the server.js i made a change like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start (route, handle) {

    function onRequest (request, response) {

        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

        console.log ("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});


        var content = route(handle, pathname);
        response.write(content); //new change;
        response.end(); // new change;

    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log ("Server has started");

}

exports.start = start;
```

Now i am getting a error as like this:

```
[ERROR] 14:02:14 TypeError
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:743:11)
    at Server.onRequest (/Users/mohamedarif/Sites/node/server.js:16:12)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:1928:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1825:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: i suppose you're referring to a http server? if thats the case you can not simply return a string (in PHP you can simply write "echo 'foo';" an it will appear in the browser. in node you have "res.write('foo');" in your httprequest handler.

Comment: yes. now i am getting error as "TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:743:11)
    at Server.onRequest (/Users/mohamedarif/Sites/node/server.js:16:12)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:1928:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1825:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
"

Comment: check method for get or post and you get request or not.

Comment: can you post a more complete code example? look at the example at http://nodejs.org/ that's a good point where you can start from.

Comment: content does not seem to be an string. do a "console.log(content);" to see if a string is present.

Comment: actually the content is a function ( where i storing ), from the function only i am return the value.. according to he route that should be "start" or "upload"

Comment: you're returning undefined from route() in the non-404 case; you seem to have omitted the "return" part of the statement...

Comment: yes, you are correct. it works fine. thanks you for highlighting issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the router part, i updated my function like this: now it's working fine.

```
function route (handle, pathname) {

    console.log ("About to route a request for " + pathname);

    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){


        return handle[pathname](); //added return;

    } else {

        console.log ("No request Handler for " + pathname);

        return "404 Not Found";

    }

}

exports.route =  route;
```